# What is the point of controller.$viewValue/controller.$modelValue?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angular-ngmodel

I'm unclear what the relation is between `scope.ngModel` and `controller.$viewValue`/`controller.$modelValue`/`controller.$setViewValue()` is, and specifically, what the point of the latter three is. For example, see [this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vm0z0rfb/):

```
<input type="text" ng-model="foo" my-directive>
```

and:

```
myApp.directive('myDirective', function($timeout) {
    return {
        require: 'ngModel', 
        restrict: 'A',
        scope: { ngModel: '=' },
        link: function (scope, element, attrs, controller) {
            function log() {
              console.log(scope.ngModel);
              console.log(controller.$viewValue);
              console.log(controller.$modelValue);
            }
            log();
            controller.$setViewValue("boorb");
            log();
            scope.$watch('ngModel', function (val) {
               console.log("val is now", val); 
            });

            $timeout(function () {
                log();
            }, 2000);

        }
    }
});
```

With the controller being:

```
function MyCtrl($scope, $timeout) {
    $scope.foo = 'ahha';
    $timeout(function () { 
        $scope.foo = "good";
    }, 1000);
}
```

The output is:

```
(index):45 ahha
(index):46 NaN
(index):47 NaN
(index):45 ahha
(index):46 boorb
(index):47 boorb
(index):53 val is now ahha
(index):53 val is now good
(index):45 good
(index):46 boorb
(index):47 boorb
```

`controller.$viewValue` did not start out as the value of the `foo` variable. Further, `controller.$setViewValue("boorb")` didn't influence `scope.ngModel` at all, nor was the update reflected in the HTML. Thus it seems there is no relation between `scope.ngModel` and `controller.$viewValue`. It seems that with anything I'd want to do, I would just use `scope.ngModel`, and watch those values. What is ever the point of using `controller.$viewValue` and `controller.$modelValue` or keeping them up to date with `scope.ngModel`?

Comment: Helpful: http://radify.io/blog/understanding-ngmodelcontroller-by-example-part-1/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The confusion here is coming from sticking a directive onto an existing directive, namely `ngInput`.

Instead, consider a fresh directive:

```
<my-directive ng-model="ugh">Sup</my-directive>
```

With:

```
  $rootScope.ugh = 40;
```

And:

```
.directive('myDirective', function () {
  return {
    require: "ngModel", 

    // element-only directive
    restrict: "E", 

    // template turns the directive into one input tag
    // 'inner' is on the scope of the *directive*
    template: "<input type='text' ng-model='inner'/>",       

    // the directive will have its own isolated scope
    scope: { }, 

    link: function (scope, element, attrs, ngModelCtrl) {
      // formatter goes from modelValue (i.e. $rootScope.ugh) to 
      // view value (in this case, the string of twice the model
      // value + '-'
      ngModelCtrl.$formatters.push(function (modelValue) {
        return ('' + (modelValue * 2)) + '-';
      });

      // render does what is necessary to display the view value
      // in this case, sets the scope.inner so that the inner
      // <input> can render it
      ngModelCtrl.$render = function () {
        scope.inner = ngModelCtrl.$viewValue;
      };

      // changes on the inner should trigger changes in the view value
      scope.$watch('inner', function (newValue) {
        ngModelCtrl.$setViewValue(newValue);
      });

      // when the view value changes, it gets parsed back into a model
      // value via the parsers, which then sets the $modelValue, which
      // then sets the underlying model ($rootScope.ugh)
      ngModelCtrl.$parsers.push(function (viewValue) {
        var sub = viewValue.substr(0, viewValue.length-1);
        return parseInt(sub)/2;
      });
    }
  };
})
```

Try it on [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/V1WuzLMw63TbqQ0M4ZKs?p=preview).

Note that `typeof ugh` stays `"number"`, even though the directive's view value is of a different type.

Answer (score 0):

`scope: { ngModel: '=' },` creates an isolated scope for the directive, which means that changes to `foo` in the directive will no longer be reflected in the parent scope of `MyCtrl`.

Also, changes made by `$setViewValue()` will not get reflected in the DOM until `controller.$render()` is called, which tells Angular to update the DOM in the next digest cycle.

But to answer the question, `NgModelController` and its methods are really only necessary if you need to create some extra-special-custom-fancy data-binding directives. For normal data input and validation, you shouldn't ever need to use it. From [the documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/ngModel.NgModelController) (emphasis mine):

> [NgModelController] contains services for data-binding, validation, CSS updates, and value formatting and parsing. It purposefully does not contain any logic which deals with DOM rendering or listening to DOM events. Such DOM related logic should be provided by other directives which make use of NgModelController for data-binding to control elements. **Angular provides this DOM logic for most input elements**.